# How to add merge strategy to my build settings

Tags: scala, sbt

Currently my build fails because the mergeStrategy isn't correct.

How can I fix this?

```
object MyAppBuild extends Build {
  import Resolvers._
  import Dependency._
  import BuildSettings._

  lazy val myApp = Project(
    id = "myApp",
    base = file("."),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
      resolvers := allResolvers,
      exportJars := true,
      libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.catalogParserDependencies,
      parallelExecution in Test := false,
      //mergeStrategy in assembly := {
        // ....
      //}

    )
  )
}
```

If I had my settings in the build.sbt file it works like this:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I want to move this logic to my Build.scala file now.

Comment: It looks like the solution is commented out in the first snippet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please migrate to `build.sbt` style. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html

```
lazy val myApp = Project(
    id = "myApp",
    base = file("."),
    settings = buildSettings ++ ... // this is likely the problem
```

The *.scala style has been discouraged in the docs and, sbt 0.13.13 officially deprecates it. One of the reasons is that `Project(...)`'s `settings` parameter is not compatible with auto plugin initialization order. If you migrate to build.sbt style it should be resolved.